# Dynamic Excel Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

- How can I make a formula that I will vertically drag down on Sheet2 that references horizontal data on Sheet1 which changes to the next column after it gathers the data?
- I need a formula in which referenced **rows stay constant while the column changes**
- Example of what the row formulas would show on sheet2 "=sheet1!A1, =sheet1!A2, sheet1!B1, =sheet1!B2, sheet1!C1, =sheet1!C2"
- The referenced image may make it clearer the objective I'm going for.
  [Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6jIK.png)

I've look up some possible ways to fix it but I can't find a way to use indexing that drags down.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX(using your photo)

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$G,MOD(ROW($ZZ1)-1),8)+226,INT((ROW($ZZ1)-1)/8)+1)
```

Where:

- `Sheet1!$B:$G` is the data range.
- Both `8`s are the pattern of rows.
- `+226` is the first row of data wanted.

Comment: If you append that with `&""` then blanks will show as zero-length string and not zeroes.

Comment: Phenomenal! Thanks a bunch! Two things:

1. Since it's survey data, there may be ~500 columns. All I would do to accustom this is change "Sheet1!$B:$XBC" correct?
2. I do apologize as I'm new to the site and am not sure if this is allowed but is there anyway you could help me with another problem dealing with a similar matter? I can compensate for the time in some way!

Again much appreciated!

Comment: @KyleSOrzel - ask another question. Put a link to this question if its important.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1538248/dynamic-excel-formulas-for-ranges
Apologies if it is explained poorly.