# Dynamic Excel Formulas For Ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

- How can I make a formula that:

  1. I can vertically drag down on Sheet2...
  2. That `TEXTJOINS` two arrays (total of 28 vertical cells) of data on Sheet1...
  3. Which after it `TEXTJOINS` those 28 cells, goes to the next row in Sheet2...
  4. Looks at the same column but different row numbers then after it does this 8 times in total...
  5. Changes to the next column while looking at the same rows from iteration 1.
- In short, I want a formula that keeps the column letter static for 8 rows then changes to the next column after those 8 rows.
- The referenced image below should make it clearer of the objective I'm going for.

[Referenced Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRRd0.png)

An alternative if this is impossible/hard is to code a python script that types the formulas with using loops then I'll just copying those to excel.
Much appreciated!

Comment: I used a simple Python script to write all the formulas but if anyone knows a way to do this within excel that would be awesome! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `INDEX` function, with mathematical arguments for the row and column, to return the desired ranges.

For example:

```
MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,8)*13+122
```

will generate the repeating series: `122,135,148,161...213`

and

```
=INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/8)+1
```

will generate the repeating series `1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, …`

So to put that in a formula, which will change the ranges as you state, for, let us say, columns `B:D`, you could use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(,TRUE,INDEX(prepVertical!$B:$D,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,8)*13+122,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/8)+1):INDEX(prepVertical!$B:$D,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,8)*13+134,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/8)+1))
```

If you need to reference more columns, just change `B:D` to refer to the desired column range.